# Using PickList of Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using PickList of Primefaces as follows:

In xhtml ....

```
<p:pickList valueChangeListener="#{bean.handlePickList}" onTransfer="submit()" value="#{bean.currentField.PICK_VALUES" id="myPickVals" var="pickVals" itemLabel="#{pickVals}" itemValue="#{pickVals}"/>
```

In the bean ....

```
public class MyFields{
    public void handlePickList(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("in handlePickList routine of MyFields.java. ");
    }
}
```

I am getting error ....

```
Property 'handlePickList' not found on type com.myproj.common.MyFields
```

How do I get the values picked by the user from the target list of PickList ?

Comment: Is this a typo on your question `value="#{bean.currentField.PICK_VALUES"` that is missing the closing `}` bracket?  Further, did you verify that the class MyFields is configured as a ManagedBean with the name `bean`?

Answer (score 0):

per [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/picklist.jsf):

The values provided to the list must be placed in primeface's DaulListModel.

In your bean:

```
private DualListModel<yourObjectType> listItems;

public DualListModel<yourObjectType> getListItems() {
   if(listItems == null){
    List<yourObjectType> listItemsSource = new ArrayList<yourObjectType>();
    List<yourObjectType> listItemsTarget = new ArrayList<yourObjectType>();

    ... populate the source and target accordingly ...

    listItems= new DualListModel<yourObjectType>(listItemsSource , listItemsTarget );
   }
    return listItems;  
}  

public void setListItems(DualListModel<yourObjectType> listItems) {  
    this.listItems = listItems;  
}
```

Place listItems into the value attribute of the jsf tag

```
value="#{bean.listItems}"
```

On submit simply access the selected list items like so:

```
getListItems().getTarget()
```

fyi, you may have to create and provide a converter for this to work with your desired object type.

Comment: Problem is resolved after rebuilding the project from scratch